# What do the empty quotations mean for value?

Tags: html

Do the empty quotes mean that multiple values can be entered for the value?

```
<input name="favoriteCities[]" value=""/>
```

Comment: It means that the value is empty. Why do you think multiple values can be entered?

Comment: no multiples inputs with the same name build a php array when submitted

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

As Nikhil mentioned. It means the value is empty of that input tag.

Run the snippet below to see the difference.

It's pretty simple:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

<p>Input with value:</p>
<input type="text" value="Hi I'm not empty">
<p>Input with empty value:</p>
<input type="text" value="">

</body>

</html>
```